# object reference is not set to an instance of an object and the number of generic arguments dosent equal the arity of the generic type definition

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Every time I open a new project in Microsoft Visual Studio it says:

> object reference is not set to an instance of an object

And when I got to open an existing project none of my code appears and then when I go to close msstudio it says:

> the number of generic arguments dosent equal the arity of the generic type definition

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Has this just started with an existing installation of VS, or has this always happened? Seems like a botched installation. Try uninstalling or repairing from the control panel.

Comment: no its just happend now

Comment: should i uninstall and reinstall

Comment: Best to reinstall I think. There are many reports of similar problems, e.g. (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/894438). They all seem to involve some brittle database handling code in VS. Think about removing extensions, if you have any installed.